# Como rodar todos os meus testes de uma vez?

Tags: visual-studio-code, flutter

Como rodar todos os testes unitários de uma vez no flutter?

Cada teste tem somente a opção `Run` como na imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então gostaria de saber como rodar todos os meus testes de uma vez sem ter que clicar em cada um.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Edit]**

Caso seus testes estejam agrupados em diversos caminhos e pastas você precisa obrigatoriamente deixar eles dentro do diretório `test` do projeto e todos os arquivos devem possuir o sufixo `_test.dart`.

Com esta configuração feita poderá ir no terminal e simplesmente aplicar o comando referente ao projeto fazendo assim todos os testes programados rodarem:

**Projeto Flutter**

```
flutter test
```

**Projeto dart**

```
pub run test
```

---

Além disso, existe a possibilidade de você agrupar seus testes e assim rodar todos presentes ali de uma única vez.

**Exemplo**

*Arquivo: test/widget_test.dart*

```dart
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

void main() {
  group('Counter', () {
    test('value should start at 0', () {
      expect(Counter().value, 0);
    });

    test('value should be incremented', () {
      final counter = Counter();

      counter.increment();

      expect(counter.value, 1);
    });

    test('value should be decremented', () {
      final counter = Counter();

      counter.decrement();

      expect(counter.value, -1);
    });
  });

  group('Counter 2', () {
    test('value should start at 0', () {
      expect(Counter().value, 0);
    });

    test('value should be incremented', () {
      final counter = Counter();

      counter.increment();

      expect(counter.value, 1);
    });

    test('value should be decremented', () {
      final counter = Counter();

      counter.decrement();

      expect(counter.value, -1);
    });
  });
}

class Counter {
  int value = 0;

  void increment() => value++;

  void decrement() => value--;
}
```

Para rodar os testes poderá fazer das seguintes formas:

- Clicar no `Run` do grupo desejado;
- Clicar na aba `Debug` do `VSCode` e iniciar o processo por lá (obs: apenas se utiliza o VSCode para desenvolvimento);
- Ir no terminal e rodar o comando `flutter test test/widget_test.dart`
  ;

---

Para maiores detalhes consulte a documentação:

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/testing/unit/introduction

https://pub.dev/packages/test#running-tests

Comment: Pode até resolver para arquivo único mas no meu caso são vários arquivos separados em diversas pastas.

Comment: @rubStackOverflow editei a resposta adicionando o cenário descrito no seu comentário. Se entendi bem o que busca creio que resolverá seu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Uma alternativa para quem prefere visualizar na aba de teste do visual studio

- Editar o arquivo `launch.json` e adicionar:

  `{
      "name": "All Tests",
      "type": "dart",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "test/",
  }`
- Selecionar `All Tests`, para rodar os teste `Crtl+F5`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]